# Disable clicking links on Kindle books

Tags: kindle, hyperlinking

I have a Kindle Paperwhite. Frequently when reading technical books (i.e. [Docker for Rails Developers](https://pragprog.com/book/ridocker/docker-for-rails-developers), I tap to go to the next page, but accidentally click a hyperlink in the content, which jumps me to a totally different page.

Usually I don't realise for a second, until what I'm reading no longer makes sense.

Is there a way to disable clicking of links inside books, or at least prompt to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is late but I haven't seen this answered yet. I have a Kindle Paperwhite 11th generation.

You can go to settings > Parental Controls > turn off Web Browser

It will prompt you to set a PIN. Now try clicking a link and the content will be blocked.